# Neo4j start error while network connection is enabled

Tags: linux, neo4j, fedora

I have some issues running neo4j server on localhost:
When I start it using `./neo4j start` it only works when there is no network connection (ethernet or wifi).

If I try to start the server when I am connected then the message `waiting for server to be ready.....` never ends and is killed after 2 minutes.

Everything is normal in console.log and messages.log.

I cannot figure out why an internet connection may cause that.
(The error occurs on each neo4j release, and I am running Fedora 20)

Edit : I have tested to shut down my firewall but it didn't change anything.

Edit2: If I start neo4j server before setting up a network connection it works fine (I can still use it once the network connection is up). The problem occurs only when I try to start the server while I have an active connection.

Here is the console log for neo4j 1.9.9 on fedora 20. It is stuck after the [main] line and the stack is generated after the 2min timeout.
I have the same behavior for each neo4j version available in the releases.

```
sudo ./neo4j console
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
10:36:57.927 [main] INFO  org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer - Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@52aa430a' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:530)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:284)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:57)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@3f32f5c' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:530)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:526)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Failed to flush file channel /home/gdaniel/Téléchargements/neo4j-community-1.9.9/data/graph.db/neostore
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.flushAll(PersistenceWindowPool.java:333)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.flushAll(CommonAbstractStore.java:560)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NeoStore.flushAll(NeoStore.java:251)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:305)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:526)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:99)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.force(FileChannelImpl.java:367)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.force(StoreFileChannel.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.flushAll(PersistenceWindowPool.java:329)
    ... 17 more
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@7a171efb' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:512)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:284)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:57)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@46b0b225' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:512)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:506)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource@7dbff9ea' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:512)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.bringToState(LifeSupport.java:419)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.add(LifeSupport.java:331)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.registerDataSource(XaDataSourceManager.java:196)
    at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.start(LuceneKernelExtension.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:506)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.<init>(IndexProviderStore.java:85)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:298)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:222)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:506)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:290)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.position(StoreFileChannel.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.position(StoreFileChannel.java:28)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.write(IndexProviderStore.java:169)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.create(IndexProviderStore.java:153)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.<init>(IndexProviderStore.java:61)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Which edition of Neo are you using (Community/Enterprise)? Have you modified default configuration at all?

Comment: I am using community édition, ans I've testés from 1.9.9 tout thé last one. Thé error occurs with a fresh installation, with défaut configurations.

Comment: I would guess that something else is using one of the ports that Neo wants and Neo is just not logging it very nicely. Check if 1337 & 7474 are free, there are probably some more too that I've forgotten.

Comment: I have tested to run it on port 80, where I have an apache server listening, and there was an explicit error message saying the port is not available. I have also listed used ports and 7474 and 1337 seems to be available.

Comment: Neo4J can't run on top of apache like that on port 80.  Neo4J is running its own web server and must be on a separate port.

Comment: I know, I was answering JohnMark13 about used ports. Since I know apache listen on port 80 I was sure to have an error. The point is that I have no error of this kind when I run it on 7474

Comment: Can you run `bin/neo4j console` to see if there are any errors? Which neo4j version are you running and which OS ?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Done, this log is exactly the same for all the version available on download

Comment: So the error occurs (attempting) to writing to a file, have you run out of file descriptors?

Comment: I don't think so, I've set the number of open files to 40000, and the most important point is that all is working fine when I don't have a network connection.

Comment: Well I guess an other option is that you are running out of memory, as those buffers will be memory mapped. De/activating networking would have an impact on various system parameters. If you're sure it's network related though, run a sniffer and see what's timing out.

Comment: No, I ran a sniffer to see what happen on localhost but nothing seems to be strange for me (I am not a network expert at all). For the moment I have a workaround: I launch neo4j when my computer starts and then I enable network. A funny fact is that neo4j server can't be started if I am connected, and webadmin console can't work if I am not. If I have more time to investigate I keep you in touch.
Anyway thank you for the support!

Comment: Just disable remote shell that should work.